# Update the DOM based on click event using service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

I'm trying to update the DOM based on a click event, by using a service.

Specifically, I'm trying to use bootstrap's alerts to alert the user when they click on a particular button on the page. I'd like to be able to call `notify.createNotification("Saved successfully")` for instance, to tell the user that they have saved successfully.

I'm using `ui-router` and have managed to abstract the notification to a (isolate scope) directive and the accompanying template. The notification currently `shows`, updated, at the head of my application (all other views inherit this view) upon $scope.createNotification() (from within the click event). This works because the child views inherit the $scope property. Clearly though this pollution and abuse of the inheritance of the $scope is not ideal, hence I'd like to move it all into a service.

I've got as far as trying to use a factory to update the `notification` object, which contains state information for the alert, i.e. display:true/false, text etc. The trouble with the factory is it just returns where it's called from, I need to be able to update the parent.

...I feel I've done 9/10ths of the work on this, but that last 1/10th is really puzzling me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Guess I'm also looking for a 'best practices' here too, I mean $scope pollution works, but it's far from ideal. Thanks

Comment: can you post an example of your factory, directive and controller from which you call notification service? it's not clear what you are doing wrong from description

Comment: can you pls post some of your sample javascript to throw more light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved using pub/sub approach.

1. Create `NotificationService` that is used to send notifications.  For callers it would look like `NotificationService.alert({text: '..', ...})`
2. Create `<notification-area>` component that subscribes to `NotificationSerivce` and displays notifications sent from anywhere.
3. `NotificationService` itself should implement pub/sub interface.  Use any implementation of `EventEmitter` (like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wolfy87-eventemitter)) or even `angular.element` to provide `on(), off(), trigger()`  methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I'm not sure the EventEmitter is quite necessary (or perhaps I'm misunderstanding that point), but otherwise a service with a pub/sub approach is what I was looking for